# linux kernel bpf C code ellipsis inside array

Tags: c, linux

What does this line mean:

```
[0 ... 255] = &&default_label
```

in the definition:

```
static const void *jumptable[256] = {
    [0 ... 255] = &&default_label,
    /* Now overwrite non-defaults ... */
    /* 32 bit ALU operations */
    [BPF_ALU | BPF_ADD | BPF_X] = &&ALU_ADD_X,
    …
};
```

http://lxr.devzen.net/source/xref/linux-4.8.15/kernel/bpf/core.c#473

Answer (score 1):

The `[0 ... 255]` notation is a GCC extension to the [designated initializer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits) syntax (that is desperately needed in standard C).  It sets elements `0` through `255` of the array (of `void *` values) to the [address of the label](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels-as-Values) `default_label` (another GCC syntax extension, but this is one that is not desperately needed in standard C).